# How to load a resource from disk in OSGI environment

Tags: resources, osgi, disk

Part 1: I've been trying to load a (XML) file as a resource from disk using bundle class loader. I can't package the file in a bundle beforehand as it'll be generated at runtime. I tried searching too, and almost always, people talk about loading resources from within a bundle (either same or different). So is it even possible to load a resource from disk in an OSGi environment using bundle classloader? If yes, how can it be done?

Part 2: Now I need to add a constraint to the above. In my complete scenario, while I'd be generating the file, it would be loaded by a third-party bundle. In this case, what could be done (generate in a certain location, any changes to classpath etc.) so that the third-party bundle's class loader could find the generated file?

Using: apache karaf 3.0.2, ubuntu 12.

Answer (score 2):

Part 1:

> So is it even possible to load a resource from disk in an OSGi environment using bundle classloader?

Resources (read-only files on the classpath) can be loaded with classloaders, not ordinary files from any folder of the disk. When you want to process the content of files from the ClassPath, you should use the classloader.

You want to generate a temporary file (generated and processed at runtime) so you should use the standard Java API for that:

```
File myTmpFile = File.createTempFile(...);
```

For more info, see the javadoc of this function: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Part 2:

The third bundle should have an API that either accepts a File, URL, Path or other type instance that can point to a file in the file system.